# How can I run this function that parses remote json when i press a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

How can I use something like this to parse remote json, but instead of running when the document is ready, run when I press a button?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $.getJSON("https://example.com/example.json", function(data){
    var name = data.fullname; //note the data.data
    alert(name);
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Before posting a question here, [read the docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/), try, look for solutions online, and if you still can't get it to work, come back here and show the effort you've put into it, as well as what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, this is what i tried but it doesn't work so i thought I would post what does work. https://jsfiddle.net/7sux3jc9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add a button

```
<button id="action_button">Click Me</button>
```

And then use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#action_button').on('click', function(){ 
  $.getJSON("https://example.com/example.json", function(data){
    var name = data.fullname; //note the data.data
    alert(name);
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: Hmm. i just tried that in fiddle... and it didn't work.

Comment: @HEXICLE You forgot to close one `});`, and the JSON URL you used does not return anything. Check that it is the correct one. Here is a working example using another URL: https://jsfiddle.net/7sux3jc9/3/

Comment: Ah, thank you! I am pretty sure the api is down right now because I used that exact link earlier and it worked... Thanks!